# Play back 24-bit wav with AudioPlayer in java

Tags: java, audio

When I play 24-bit wav files in java they don't play. 16-bit files work fine.

I am using:

```
InputStream audioInputStream = new FileInputStream(soundFile);
AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(audioInputStream);
AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
```

I realise this method is depreciated, but I am using it for other reasons (reading changeable files from a jar for instance).

Is there any way of playing 24-bit files on java (perhaps internally converting them?). I am using linux, but this needs to work cross-platform.

Comment: Do you get an exception playing 24 bit? If so what? Java on the Mac started supporting 24 bit from Java 1.7

Comment: It doesn't play the sound. No exception given.

Comment: That's why I am trying to bulk convert them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608675/bulk-converting-wav-files-to-16-bit-with-ffmpeg-in-batch-from-unix-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible in java on my linux.

So I bulk converted the files with this script:

```
for f in $(find ./ -name '*.wav'); do 
ffmpeg -i $f -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 ${f%.wav}z.wav; 
rm $f;
mv ${f%.wav}z.wav $f;
done
```